# How to SelectNodes with multiple attribute crieria using XML in ASP classic?

Tags: xml, asp-classic

I know how to selectnodes where a specific attribute has a specific value.  For example, I know how to select nodes "person" nodes which have a value of `strID` for attribute `id`;

```
Set oDOM = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument")
oDOM.loadXML strXML

Set oNodes = oDOM.selectNodes("/people/person[@id='" & strID & "']")
```

Now suppose person nodes also had an attribute `name`.  How would I select "person" nodes where `id` has value `strID` and `name` has value `strName`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:-

```
Set oNodes = oDOM.selectNodes("/people/person[@id='" & strID & "' and @name='" & strName & "']")
```

Comment: Note that "AND" does not work. It is case sensitive so it must be "and".